# Class cast exception occur while updating OpenJDK version from 11.0.2 to 11.0.10

Tags: java, bouncycastle, classcastexception, openjdk-11, sslexception

After updating the minor version of OpenJDK , I am getting an error in any API call with HTTPS protocol

The same code was working fine with the older version.

Older version(Working fine):

```
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

New Version(Not working):

```
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: class org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.edec.BCXDHPublicKey cannot be cast to class java.security.interfaces.XECPublicKey (org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.edec.BCXDHPublicKey is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @2e0fa5d3; java.security.interfaces.XECPublicKey is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.edec.BCXDHPublicKey cannot be cast to class java.security.interfaces.XECPublicKey (org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.edec.BCXDHPublicKey is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @2e0fa5d3; java.security.interfaces.XECPublicKey is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.XDHKeyExchange$XDHEPossession.<init>(XDHKeyExchange.java:108)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.NamedGroup$XDHFunctions.createPossession(NamedGroup.java:754)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.NamedGroup.createPossession(NamedGroup.java:394)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLKeyExchange$T13KeyAgreement.createPossession(SSLKeyExchange.java:568)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLKeyExchange.createPossessions(SSLKeyExchange.java:84)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.KeyShareExtension$CHKeyShareProducer.produce(KeyShareExtension.java:257)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension.produce(SSLExtension.java:563)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.produce(SSLExtensions.java:253)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloKickstartProducer.produce(ClientHello.java:650)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.kickstart(SSLHandshake.java:525)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.kickstart(ClientHandshakeContext.java:107)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:232)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:433)
... 11 common frames omitted
```

I am using `URLConnection` to establish the new connection with any URL but at the time of connection `URL connection.connect()`.

Any solutions or workaround for this?
How can I downgrade the minor version?

Comment: Please give the exact BouncyCastle jar name and version that you are using.

Comment: See also https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/589 and https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/881, particularly comments relating to use of a "fat jar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of bouncycastle class not found exception.
need to add bouncy castle dependency to your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file.

add below dependency for maven and gradle.

For Gradle ::
`implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: '1.68'`

For Maven ::

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.68</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain, why it did work on Java 11.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, for google completeness, is that the underlying API changed when the JDK added support for the X25519 and X448 ECDH protocols. Bouncycastle [had to use multi-release classes](https://github.com/ok3141/bc-java/commit/18c3bb7cb6f17b14402501623239433f3f06ae56) to fix the issue. So you update your dependency.

If it's not your software the work around, as in [this issue](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/589), normally is to remove support of these protocols, like such:

```
java -Djdk.tls.namedGroups="secp256r1, secp384r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072" ...
```

or

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Djdk.tls.namedGroups=\"secp256r1, secp384r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072\""
```